# How to send user data to a different custom spring boot application for authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, filtering

Imagine there are two spring boot applications, Auth-service-app and Main-service-app. Main-service-app will interact with a user (take username and password from the user) and Auth-service-app will authenticate the user. Auth-service-app uses the basic auth implementation from spring security. Now the question is how can the user data can be passed from Main-service-app to Auth-service-app for authentication?

Comment: Expose a rest API at Auth-service-app, which will return the authentication status for the user. Main-service-app can invoke the API exposed by Auth-service-app.

Comment: @Reji thanks for your comment. But how to configure it from Main-service-app.